# A pod include a third party framework can't import in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I want to create a pod which only contain the framework and the bundle resources provided by the other company's open platform.But I came across some problem.

#### In the Objective-C project

At the first time ,I just created a podspec file , which only included the framework by using the `s.ios.vendored_frameworks` and the bundle resources.And it pass the validation when I run `pod spec lint`.Then I imported it into an Objective-C project in the podfie,and it work when I run `pod install` and I can import the framework into my code with `#import <xxx/xxx.h>`

[image]

But I found that in the **xcworkspace** project file ,it automatic generated a scheme ,like the picture above.It seem the generated scheme is a target for mac. **Call it situation A**

If I add a custom new class ,named Version.h and Version.m in the pod, and update the podspec file by using `s.source_files  = "Classes", "Version/*.{h,m}"`,then when I run `pod install` ,It generated a static library,this is what I want and the result I think it should be. **Call it situation B**

So the questions is :

- Why does the pod generate a scheme for mac when I didn't include any custom class file,and doest it matter?
- why does the pod generate a static library when I iclude a custom class ?

#### In the swift project

The second part is I also need to import the pod into a swift project. And I also came across the simular problem.

At this time , in the podfie I use the `use_frameworks!` keyword.

In situation A: I can not import the framework ,*no such module xxx* ,the error from compiler.

In situation B: *could not build Objective-C moulde xxx* ,error from compiler,I try clean and delete the DerivedData directory,but it didn't work. And it does not generate the modulemap and xx-umbrella.h file. The same problem I found that when I use the google ad sdk

```
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', "~> 7.4.0"
```

In situation A,when the pod generate pods project,it does not install the target from my pod .In situation B,it install the target from my pod. like the following log from pod

```
//situation b
- Creating Pods project
- Adding source files to Pods project
- Adding frameworks to Pods project
- Adding libraries to Pods project
- Adding resources to Pods project
- Linking headers
- Installing targets
- Installing target `AliPay` iOS 8.0

//situation a
- Creating Pods project
- Adding source files to Pods project
- Adding frameworks to Pods project
- Adding libraries to Pods project
- Adding resources to Pods project
- Linking headers
- Installing targets
- Installing target `Pods-NewCategory` iOS 8.0
  - Generating Info.plist file at `Pods/Target Support
  Files/Pods-NewCategory/Info.plist`
  - Generating module map file at `Pods/Target Support
  Files/Pods-NewCategory/Pods-NewCategory.modulemap`
  - Generating umbrella header at `Pods/Target Support
  Files/Pods-NewCategory/Pods-NewCategory-umbrella.h`
- Running post install hooks
```

- So why the pod can not work with swift project, do I do something work with using pod or because the framework.

The pod I created host on [github](https://github.com/NikoTung/AliPay),the tag 0.0.1 created on situation A, tag 0.0.2 created on situation B.

Comment: Did it solved your issue ?

Comment: @Loegic Thank you for your answer.When I use those pods as local pod (pod spec file inside the project) to my project,the situation A in objective-c project solved. But the situation B still not be solved.

Comment: Did you made all the changements I wrote ? what are your issue now ?

Answer (score 1):

For the situation A,

You should specify which platform the pod is for in the pod spec like so :

```
s.platform     = :ios
s.development_target = '8.0'
```

For the situation B,

In swift you can't use static libraries, that's why cocoa pods introduced the property `use_frameworks!`

To get rid of the module not found error, you have to specify a module map file containing the umbrella header for it.

Comment: I'm not sure i follow you there, i have pretty much the same issue, i am on a project using xcode 7, swift 2.0, i'm adding an objc pod of my own, i did set the "use_frameworks!" up of my podfile. 
When i try to run, i get a fail because the compiler can't find the 3rd party SDK used in my pod. But this SDK is in the sources and it's the #import<SDK.h> that doesn't work... i don't know why, so i guess it's that module map file you're talking about that i'm missing... 
Any idea on what i should do to get it working?

Comment: Maybe you just have to change the #import<SDK.h> to #import<SDK/SDK.h>, sometimes it works

Comment: yep my bad actually it is already #import <SDK/SDK.h> and it doesn't work, and i tried with #import <SDK.h>  but it doesn't work aswell... 

i'm trying to find a solution but i hit a wall as of now

Comment: What is the error exactly ? you should create another question as this is not the same issue

Comment: yep that's what i'm thinking about. To be a bit more clear, i have a pod called myPodForSDKLib that contains only a  myPodForSDKManager.h/.m and SDK.frameworks. myPodForSDKManager.h has an #import <SDK/SDK.h>, and when i add all this to my swift project and when i try to compile the project, i get an error on the #import line : 'SDK/SDK.h' file not found

Comment: Create a new question with all the available informations, screenshots and I will answer there, extended discussion aren't allowed in comment

Comment: I was going to, but a colleague found the solution, we had to put #import <SDK/SDK.h> in the myPodForSDKManager.m file and not the .h thx anyway for the help, you'r answer put us on the tracks :)

Comment: I wanted to say that before (hiding the import in a .m file) but as I didn't have all the informations.. Anyway glad to hear that's solved !